# ORM for Graph, networkX Django saving

Tags: python, django, graph, networkx

Now i need a help of society. I have a project based on django / python and network x.
How can i store my network x graph in Database?

```
For example i have G = nx.Graph()
```

[graph tutorial >](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/index.html)

**How can i save it to database to read later?**

- I tried to use just trees before and save them with MPTT model, but i
  need edges, so i decided to use network x
- I want probably to have    model for this, so i can just graph.save()

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
import networkx as nx
nx.write_gml(G,"test.gml")
```

to save your graph and

```
G = nx.read_gml("test.gml")
```

to retrieve it

To go further you can use Neo4J/Titan which are very good java graph databases.
You can access them in Python with Bulbs : https://github.com/espeed/bulbs

You can also try GrapheekDB : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grapheekdb which is a pure Python graph database, mostly intended for prototyping (disclaimer : I'm the author of this database)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i asked for. i will try bulbs.